# ArrayBuffer vs ArrayBuilder in scala

Tags: scala

What is the difference between scala.collections.mutable.ArrayBuilder and scala.collections.mutable.ArrayBuffer? If, for instance, I need to build an Array[Int], which is preferrable to use? Is there any perfomance difference, like in java.lang.StringBuffer and java.lang.StringBuilder?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`ArrayBuilder` is a `Builder`, and builders are meant to be used to construct other collections by adding elements to them. Builders are not usually meant to be used directly in client code.

`ArrayBuffer` is a `Buffer` and `Seq` -- buffers are sequences to which you can efficiently append elements. Sequences come with a lot of auxiliary operations.

You probably need an `ArrayBuffer`. It is meant to be used as an alternative to the `ArrayList` in Java. The `ArrayBuffer` class is a fully-powered sequence collections with all the bulk data operations like `foreach`, `map`, `filter`, `zip` and friends, unlike `ArrayBuilder` which is equipped only with `+=` to add elements and `result` to obtain the array at the end.

One place where you might prefer an `ArrayBuilder` is when you are instantiating it for a primitive type like `Int` and you care about performance. In this case the `ArrayBuilder` variants are specialized for different primitive types and hold an underlying array of a proper primitive type, whereas an `ArrayBuffer` always holds an object array underneath -- every primitive you add to it undergoes boxing.

To instantiate an array buffer:

```
new ArrayBuffer[Int] // gives you an array buffer that will hold boxed integers
```

To instantiate an array builder:

```
new ArrayBuilder.ofInt // gives you a manually specialized array builder that will hold real primitives
```

Comment: The short answer is that `Builder` are (semi-) internal classes meant for those writing new collections classes (whether as part of the standard library or extensions to it).

Comment: Great answer. In my case, it seems, I need an ArrayBuilder: I need to add elements in a while loop to 'something', and then transform this 'something' in an Array (it has to be an array, for java interoperability). This 'something' should be an ArrayBuilder, based on this info.

Comment: If you know the exact primitive type for the elements, use an `ArrayBuilder` to get an appropriate array type back. If you use `ArrayBuffer`, you can still play tricks to get the array out of it, but it will have the type `Object[]` from the Java point of view, that is, `Array[AnyRef]` in Scala terms.

Answer (score 11):

I timed it and building an array with `ArrayBuilder` is noticeably faster:

With `ArrayBuffer`:

```
real    0m40.348s
user    0m29.544s
sys 0m1.017s
```

With `Array Builder`:

```
real    0m8.392s
user    0m4.769s
sys 0m0.330s
```

My code:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.{ArrayBuffer, ArrayBuilder}

object MyObject {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {

        for (i <- 0 until 100) {
            arrayBuilderMade
            // or arrayBufferMade

        }
    }

    def arrayBufferMade {

        var aBuffer = new ArrayBuffer[Int]()

        for (i <- 0 until 1000000) {
            aBuffer += i
        }

        println(aBuffer.toArray.length)
    }

    def arrayBuilderMade {

        var aBuilder = new ArrayBuilder.ofInt

        for (i <- 0 until 1000000) {
            aBuilder += i
        }

        println(aBuilder.result.length)
    }
}
```

And

```
time scala my_code.scala
```

Comment: The difference will be way less (almost negligible) for non-primitive type (e. g. `String`). Boxing/unboxing of `Int` takes its toll.